# Using observable filter in Angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, filter, rxjs, observable

I am trying to filter an `Observable` and use it in a loop in my view but it will not render.

```
this.client_comments$ = this.comments$.filter(comment => comment.commentable_type == 'Client')
```

where `comments$` is:

```
comments = new BehaviorSubject([]);
this.comments.next(this.client.comments) // this.client.comments is an array of comment objects
this.comments$ = this.comments.asObservable()
```

The result is correct, but when I try to render it using the async pipe, nothing is displayed:

```
<p *ngFor="let comment of client_comments$ | async">{{ comment.body }}</p>
```

and after looking at the object in the devtools I see there seems to be a nested observable (2 sources):

```
client_comments$: Observable
    operator: FilterOperator {predicate: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
    source: Observable
        source: BehaviorSubject
            ...
            value: (...)
```

whereas my other observables have the following structure (1 source):

```
comments$: Observable
    operator: FilterOperator {predicate: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
    source: BehaviorSubject
        ...
        value: (...)
```

is there a way to get my `client_comments$` to work in n `async` pipe?  **Please note that the `client_comments$` observable array contains all desired values**

Here's a [fiddle showing the structure change you can inspect in the console](https://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/206/)

Here's a [fiddle showing the issue with the `async` pipe in the view](https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/338/)

Comment: What's `comments$`?

Comment: `comments$: Observable<any[]>`.  It's an Observable list

Comment: it seems like after filtering `comments$` the structure of the observable is changed

Comment: Can you show the code that creates `comments$`?

Comment: I've added it above

Comment: You have `comments = new BehaviorSubject([]);` and then `this.comments$ = this.comments.asObservable()` so where `this.comments` comes from?

Comment: comments is initialized with an empty array in `comments.next([])`

Comment: You're never assigning anything to `this.comments`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164274/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-martin).

Comment: It comes from an API and is turned into an observable.  I'm not following the issue?  I'm just concerned with the filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you don-voted me, but your problem is that you dont understand the the **different data types**.

In your fiddle, replace:

```
filteredComments$ = this.comments$.filter(function(comment) {
    comment.commentable_type == 'Client'
})
```

With`;

```
filteredComments$ = this.comments$.map(function(ARRAY) {
  return ARRAY.filter(function(comment) {
    return comment.commentable_type == 'Client'
  })
});
```

And see yourself...

**Original post:**

---

Looks like you try to filter not the emitted items but what emitted items to return - `comment => comment.commentable_type == 'Client'`

So that above is equivalent to `[array of objects emitted by your subject].commentable_type == 'Client'` what is not true for any emitted item. Instead try:

```
this.client_comments$ = this.comments$.map(item => item.filter(comment => comment.commentable_type == 'Client'))
```

Comment: the filter is working properly, and giving me the correct values so this is not the case.  The only thing that's not working is the structure of the returned item

Comment: @Jeremy Thomas - here `this.comments$.filter(comment =>` your  `comment` is an array. So you cant filter it by referencing the whole array. You must iterate through its items and filter them. How you know that filter does work? Have you tried what I wrote?

Comment: I thought the the rxjs `filter` function is given an observable array, and the predicate is an object in the array

`const source = Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);`
`const example = source.filter(num => num % 2 === 0);`

Comment: ...and no it doesn'ty work with your solution.  I found a workaround so it's not important

Comment: @JeremyThomas Observable.from is going to create a sequence from an iterable item - as in, it's going to emit a singular value at a time. But in your case (this.comments$.filter(comment => ...) like J.D said, it's going to be an array

Comment: @Jeremy Thomas - if you solved it, please post it as an answer :)

Comment: I mean I solved it at the service level when I receive the data initially.  It's not a solution to the problem I had, which involves filtering

Comment: I created 2 fiddles, one showing the issue where you can inspect the console and see the filter working, but the structure changed (https://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/206/) and one showing my issue is a view (https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/338/)